# What is the benefit of using kwargs (or args) over a simple dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I'd like to get idea why should I use kwargs or args over passing in a simple dict (or tuple in case of args)?

I wrote a very simple code snippet to check what exactly happens and I can't find any pros to use kwargs over a dict. If anyone could tell me why should I use those I'd be happy.
Now as I can see it just more pythonic but don't makes any difference. Also if you use a simple dict then it's more readable because all the languages can do that but not the kwargs way.

```py
def test_normal(input: dict):
    for element in input.items():
        print('Type: {}, raw: {}'.format(type(input), input))
        print('key: {}, value: {}'.format(element[0], element[1]))

def test_kwargs(**kwargs):
    for element in kwargs.items():
        print('Type: {}, raw: {}'.format(type(kwargs), kwargs))
        print('key: {}, value: {}'.format(element[0], element[1]))

test_normal(dict(name='Joseph'))
test_kwargs(name='Joseph')
```

```
Type: <class 'dict'>, raw: {'name': 'Joseph'}
key: name, value: Joseph
Type: <class 'dict'>, raw: {'name': 'Joseph'}
key: name, value: Joseph
```

Comment: Because `test_kwargs(name='Joseph')` looks much better than `test_normal(dict(name='Joseph'))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Your question is too broad, try expanding out your example to a function that requires more than 1 parameter for a start.

Comment: The idea for `kwargs` is a clean interface to allow input parameters that aren't necessarily predetermined. This way you don't have to throw it in a dictionary. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs) as well.

Comment: @busybear Yes, you don't have to throw it into a dictionary but when you try to use it in the method it will be a dictionary anyway.

Comment: @buran Not duplicate I guess because I'm not asking how it works but why or when to use it

Comment: @Guireg, check this question - same as yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112721/what-is-the-difference-in-args-kwargs-vs-calling-with-tuple-and-dict which was declared duplicate and redirected to the one I refer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference in \*args, \*\*kwargs vs calling with tuple and dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112721/what-is-the-difference-in-args-kwargs-vs-calling-with-tuple-and-dict)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are different things and both have their use-cases. Just a rule of thumb: **If it looks like a function parameter, it should be a function parameter**.

There are several neat use-cases for `*args` and `**kwargs`. One of which is passing through parameters that you don't care about at this point:

Say you have class `Base` and class `A` inherited from `Base`:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, n, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.n = n
```

As you see class `A` does not care about `Base`'s `__init__` parameters, so it just passes everything (except `n` that it needs) forward. So if you were to change `Base`'s `__init__` you would not need to change `A`.

But when you create `A` object you would pass parameters normally:

```
a = A(5, 3, y=6, z=42)
```

---

A similar idea is when you implement a decorator which you'd like to use on a function with any kind and number of arguments:

```
def say_hello_first(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, *kwargs):
        print('Hello')
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@say_hello_first
def foo(x):
    print(x)

@say_hello_first
def bar(a, b, c=3.14):
    print((a + b) * c)
```

then:

```
>>> foo(42)
Hello
42

>>> bar(1, 2, c=3)
Hello
9
```

Comment: The second part makes sense with the decorators.